# PHP-JQuery: problems with recaptcha

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha

I've an HTML file with two form, one for registration, another one for login.
So,when I noticed that recaptcha doesn't allow to put more that one captcha per page, I thinked that I could show a captcha only for the registration form or the login one (if all fields are empty). So, I tried to start with the registration form,but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
...
<form> 
 <input type="text" id="username_reg"></input>
 <input type="text" id="email_reg"></input>
 <input type="password" id="password_reg"></input>
 <input type="password" id="cpassword_reg"></input>
 <span id="captcha_reg"></span>
</form>
...
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
 function()
 {
  $("#username_reg").change(
   function()
   {
    if ($('#username_reg').val()!='' && 
        $('#email_reg').val()!='' && 
        $('#password_reg').val()!='' &&
        $('#cpassword_reg').val()!='')
    {
     $('#captcha_reg').html('<?php require_once("recaptchalib.php");echo recaptcha_get_html("mypubkey"); ?>'
     );
    }
   }
  );
  $("#email_reg").change(
   //same code as first
  );
  $("#password_reg").change(
   //same code as first
  );
  $("#cpassword_reg").change(
   //same code as first
  );
 }
);
```

I know the JQuery code isn't so optimized (from the point of view of memory resources), but I don't have in mind any other way to achieve that. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar once. What you want to do is have a hidden template element that you turn into the reCaptcha widget, then move that whole widget to the appropriate form `div` container when the user switches to view that respective section. You can clear/reset your fields at that time, or call to get a new captcha challenge, before showing it to the user in that section. Here's an example:

See the jQuery API documentation for the `append()` operation: http://api.jquery.com/append/

HTML:

```
...
<div id="login_container">
<form> 
 <input type="text" id="username_reg"></input>
 <input type="text" id="email_reg"></input>
 <input type="password" id="password_reg"></input>
 <input type="password" id="cpassword_reg"></input>
</form></div>
<div id="captcha_template" style="display:none;">
 <span id="captcha_reg">
       <?php 
           require_once("recaptchalib.php");
           echo recaptcha_get_html("mypubkey"); 
       ?>
 </span>
</div>
...
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will move the `#captcha_reg` span and its contents to the `#login_container` div when the DOM is ready.
    $('#login_container').append($('#captcha_reg'));
});
```

Comment: but to move the widget to the div container I have to do a `$('#switched_from').html('')` and a `$('#switched_to').html('_reCaptcha php code_')` in JQuery,but when I puts the reCaptcha php code inside JQuery it doesn't work.

Comment: No, you don't. I'll update my answer to show you how.

Comment: The reason why your recaptcha PHP code fails is because jQuery doesn't run PHP code, it runs JavaScript. Therefore you need to run your recaptcha PHP code from your PHP/HTML view script, and just use jQuery to move the rendered element to the correct container when the user takes the desired action (ie clicking on login vs register)

Comment: But reCaptcha won't let you show two widgets (also if one is with `display:none`, it's considered as well).

Comment: there is only one widget, it gets moved in the DOM

Comment: but `append` will add, but not delete the old one.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for DOM operations in jQuery. When you specify an existing element for the object to append, it moves it. http://api.jquery.com/append/